# How to profile a module with Azure profiling?

Tags: azure

I have all my custom logic in a DLL, it has namespace LinkLibrary.

The main web application call the initial function of the DLL in the Application_Start.

All other page requests are directed to the DLL with the below page director

Now, in the profiling result, it only show one call from the Applcation_Start, nothing about what happen in the DLL.

So how should I set to let the profiler sample calls in the DLL?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to instrument the dependent DLLs using the VSInstr command (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182402.aspx) and then add a reference to the instrumented DLL.  You should also be able to automate this at build time by using MSBuild scripts or post-build commands in VS.

Comment: thanks, seems you give me a direction to check, could you give me more info about setting this in Azure?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  This is the same as you do it now, you just change the references in your project before you deploy.

Comment: To enable profiling when publish to Azure, I just need check the "enable profiling" checkbox, nothing else. I guess I am not sure which references I can set and where are they.